# iphone navigate back to app from external page

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have an iphone app that I want to be able to navigate to an external page and then have a back button when pressed take me back to my apps page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIWebView. Push a UIViewController containing a UIWebView onto your current view controller, ensuring it's a UINavigationController of course. Here's a short example of how to do this (though you should make a proper UIViewController subclass in practise):

```
    UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [webViewController.view addSubview:[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Also consider disabling further navigation through the webview if you only want to show a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using childBrowser? This will allow you to open a simple webView ( no safari chrome ) that can go to any website, and you can customize it using the childBrowser.xib it comes with a done button as well as a few other navigation options, such as back and open in safari...

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser